# How much should a gambler stake if he receives $\$30$ if there are four or more spades among the six cards drawn?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Being new to this chapter I chanced upon the following question which left me scratching my head as I do not know how to approach this question.

> A game is played such that a gambler pays a stake to draw six cards
>   from one pack, without replacement, and receives $30 if there are four
>   or more spades among the six drawn. Otherwise, he receives nothing.
>   What is a fair stake price for him to pay ?

The ans is $0.86$

I have tried ways to reach this ans however to no avail, help me please?

I have a feeling that this $E(X) = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} x P(X= x)$ formula is used to solve this question.

Comment: Do you know how to find the probability that a six-card hand contains at least four spades?

Comment: Asumming the pack has 52 cards and each deck has 13 spades, then having to find at least 4 spades is:.        (1/6)(13/52)+(2/6)(13/52)+(3/6)(13/52)+(4/6)(13/52) this is what I think.

Comment: The probability of choosing exactly $k$ spades and $6 - k$ non-spades when six cards are drawn from a standard deck is $$\frac{\binom{13}{k}\binom{52 - 13}{6 - k}}{\binom{52}{6}} = \frac{\binom{13}{k}\binom{39}{6 - k}}{\binom{52}{6}}$$  Hence, the probability of selecting four or more spades when six cards are drawn is $$\frac{\binom{13}{4}\binom{39}{2} + \binom{13}{5}\binom{39}{1} + \binom{13}{6}\binom{39}{0}}{\binom{52}{6}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Fair stake price = $n\cdot p=30\cdot\frac{\binom{13}{4}\cdot\binom{39}{2}+\binom{13}{5}\cdot\binom{39}{1}+\binom{13}{6}\cdot\binom{39}{0}}{\binom{52}{6}}\approx 0.86$, where $p$ - probability to draw at least 4 spades.

Comment: @ N. F. Taussig thx:) corrected